# Unknown operation?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, variational-analysis

What that operation means (square symbol), and what's her name? I found it in an article about sweeping process, it is very important to me to understand the rest of the paper. Thank you
[image]

Comment: I think it's just a unrendered character. Just means the processor didn't know how to compile the character and render it.

Comment: I suggest consulting reference $[38]$.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the right character! +,°, x didn't work!

Comment: it is very old one 1967 unfound on the internet

Comment: What is the name of the paper?

Comment: A different paper by the same authors seems to define that operation in connection with what they call the "Moreau envelope" (see article page 63 [here](http://www.yokohamapublishers.jp/online-p/Pafa/vol4/pafav4n1p59.pdf), just above "Proposition 2.1"). In the same context, other authors also use the square symbol for the "infimal convolution operator", e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.05795.pdf) on p.9. (I am not qualified at all in this field, but happened to notice these in Google search.)

Comment: This symbol is usually used for the inf-convolution, see the convex conjugate page on wikipedia.

Comment: thank you Mr. r.e.s and Mr. Emmanuel for your ansewrs, it is the inf-convolution.